# Design custom query builder with filters

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Let me explain the question first and then few of my solutions to the problem. (Would have surely come to many people but i am not sure how to solve it with clean code)

Q: Have a mysql database, want to query based on multiple and/or where conditions.
E.g. where column1 = 3 and column2 not like "ab%"

A simple solution ( as i am using php zend query builder)

```
if(column1)
$query->where(conditions);
if(column2)
$query->where(conditions);
.
.
.
if(columnn)
$query->join(some params)
      ->where(conditions);
```

Or second way

Create multiple functions and pass the data through them.

Which is a better implementation? Is there any article written about same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause should look like this:

```
where
    (:p1 is null or col1 = :p1)
    or (
        (:p2 is null or col2 = :p2)
        and
        (:p3 is null or col3 like '%:p3')
    )
```

The `:p` are the parameters. If that parameter is not given than pass it as `null`.

Comment: that is very true, i am fine with the implementation, wanted to ask really if its a right way or there can be other design option for the same.